# Why is bindAttr not working with disabled? Is this a bug?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to bind the disabled state of a Bootstrap button to a property like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-large" href="#" {{bindAttr disabled="isDisabled"}} >. . .</a>
```

In the following Fiddle, the initial state of disabled on the button is correctly set to the initial value of isDisabled (try changing it). Clicking the checkbox changes the value of isDisabled, and the p tag is correctly bound to display it, but the button refuses to respond. Is this a bug?

[Please see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gazmcghee/wQC2S/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<a>` tag doesn't have a `disabled` property (check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)). This works:

```
<button class="btn btn-large" 
        {{bindAttr disabled="isDisabled"}}>. . .</button>
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wQC2S/7/).

Comment: OK, yes, I did try that at one stage, but something else must have been wrong at the time. Thanks